# node.js writeFileSync

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to populate a database with pictures paths & names using Node.js.
What I am trying to do is the following : 
- A function send a list of pictures as Base64 string.
- Another function receive this list, loop through it, convert it into picture and get the path back.

I'm pretty new to node.js so I might be doing something really stupid.

Here is the reception code :

```
app.post('/chatBot/moreinfo/create', function (req, res) {
returnList = '';
res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
//IF LIST IS NOT EMPTY
if (req.body.imgList.length !== 0) {
  const imagePath = '/var/lib/SMImageBank/';
  const regex = /^data:image\/(.*);.*$/i;
  const listePicture = req.body.imgList;
  // LOOPING INTO THE LIST
  req.body.imgList.map ( function (element) {
    const file = element;
    const filetype = file.match(regex)[1];
    var picLink2 = '';
    const base64data = file.replace(/^data:image\/.*;base64,/, "");
    const latin1data = new Buffer(base64data, 'base64').toString('latin1');
    const filename = new Date().getTime() + '' + new Date().getMilliseconds() + "." + filetype;
    fs.mkdir(imagePath, () => {
      fs.writeFile(imagePath + filename, latin1data, "latin1", function (err, content) {
        if (err) {
          routerLog(req, {'type': 'error', 'content': err} );
          res.sendStatus(500);
        }
        else {
          if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production")
            picLink2 = 'http://****.fr/image/' + filename;
          else if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "test")
            picLink2 = 'http://dev.****.fr:8010/image/' + filename;
          else if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "master")
            picLink2 = 'http://dev.****.fr:8008/image/' + filename;
          else{
            picLink2 = 'http://*****.com:8008/image/' + filename;
          }
        }
      });
    })
    console.log(picLink2);
    returnList = returnList + ";" + picLink2;
  });
}
MoreInfo.create(req.body, function (ret) {
  res.send(ret);
  routerLog(req);
})
```

});

What I want to do is to be able to access the variable "picLink2" from outside the writeFile & mkdir function so I can populate my returnList at each iteration. Obviously as node.js is asynchronous I can't access to picLink2 content from outside fs.writeFile() function. I know there has been a ton of question about this and lot of the answers are to put the code inside the writeFile()/readFile() function but I don't see how I can do it here since the writeFile() function is inside a map that is iterating into a list.

I'm new to the asynchronous world and I don't see how I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `writeFileSync` for a synchronous operation if that doesn't hurt performance.

Comment: I tried that earlier and I still get an empty string if I try to log it outside of the wrifteFileSync().